# find -mindepth -prune conflict?

Tags: find

I have a dir structure like:

```
gameplay/ch1_of_182/ajax.googleapis.com/...
gameplay/ch1_of_182/platform.twitter.com/...
gameplay/ch1_of_182/privacy-policy.truste.com/...
gameplay/ch1_of_182/www.facebook.com/...
gameplay/ch1_of_182/www.gameplay.com/...
gameplay/ch1_of_182/www-mega.gameplay.com/...
gameplay/ch2_of_182/ajax.googleapis.com/...
gameplay/ch2_of_182/platform.twitter.com/...
gameplay/ch2_of_182/privacy-policy.truste.com/...
gameplay/ch2_of_182/www.facebook.com/...
gameplay/ch2_of_182/www.gameplay.com/...
gameplay/ch2_of_182/www-mega.gameplay.com/...
...
gameplay/ch182_of_182/ajax.googleapis.com/...
gameplay/ch182_of_182/platform.twitter.com/...
gameplay/ch182_of_182/privacy-policy.truste.com/...
gameplay/ch182_of_182/www.facebook.com/...
gameplay/ch182_of_182/www.gameplay.com/...
gameplay/ch182_of_182/www-mega.gameplay.com/...
```

created using wget. Now I want to delete all of the directories and all the files they contain except for the two directories with "gameplay.com" in their name.

I have been trying different variants of:

```
find . -mindepth 2 ! -path "*gameplay.com" -prune -exec rm -r {} \;
```

but without luck.

When run from the gameplay parent dir, the 4 of 6 directories in each of the 182 directories (actually only using 1 for testing purposes) that do not contain the "gameplay.com" name pattern are deleted along with all their contents, as desired. And although the 2 directories that do contain the "gameplay.com" name pattern are left undeleted, all the files contained within each are deleted, which is not good.

I thought the `-prune` option was supposed to let `find` know to basically ignore the directory specified, but I must be specifying it wrong, because that is not happening, leaving me with two empty directories in each of the 182 parent dirs.

I think there is a potential conflict with the `-mindepth` and `-prune` options, but because I am running the command from the gameplay parent directory, without it all 182 child directories, each containing two directories I want left in tact, are deleted.

I guess I could write a `for` loop to cycle thru each dir, but it seems to me `find` should be able to accomplish this task in one foul swoop if someone doesn't mind shedding some light how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically, this is `find . -mindepth 2 \( ! -path "*gameplay.com" \) -a \( -prune \) -a \( -exec rm -r {} \; \)`

So since your `-prune` comes after the path check, it's never gotten to if your path check is false. Try switching the order.

```
find . -mindepth 2 -prune ! -path "*gameplay.com" -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Comment: that's the fix. But funny in the man page there is the example: `find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print` which I guess let me feel confident that my position of the `-prune` option could not be the problem. Don't always believe what ya read I guess.

Comment: I too learned the hard way that the relative position of `-prune` matters. The manual is weak.